# Kafka Streams: ConsumerRebalanceListener implementation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Can you please advise how the below class needs to be registered in the streams config?

```java
public class MyConsumerRebalanceListener implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {

  static final Logger oLogger = Logger.getLogger(StreamConsumerRebalanceListener.class);

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    for (TopicPartition p : partitions) {
        oLogger.info(p + " partitions has been assigned to the stream instance");
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    for (TopicPartition p : partitions) {
        oLogger.warn(p + " partitions has been removed from the stream instance");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kafka Streams does not expose an API to specify a custom `ConsumerRebalanceListener` because Kafka Streams uses its own implementation that is passed to the internally used `KafkaConsumer`.

Note, that the internally used listener logs the assignment in INFO mode and also some additional logs in DEBUG mode. Thus, it should not be required to add additional custom logging.

If this is a critical feature, feel free to create a feature request JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA

**Update:**

If you use a `Processor` (or `Transformer` or similar), you might be able to use `init()` and `close()` instead. Those are called after partitions are assigned and before partitions get revoked.